# Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am new to Pl Sql. I am trying to run procedure and getting these errors:

> Encountered the symbol  "Create" with  begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with
>              
>              << continue close current delete fetch lock
>             insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
>             merge pipe purge:

I have tried searching for what causes these errors and for examples similar to this, but results were not sufficient. And this is my script:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CommandScript IS
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE sf_tmp'; 
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN IF SQLCODE != -942 
       THEN RAISE; 
       END IF; 

create table sf_tmp(smcard varchar2(17),p_line varchar2(1000));  

INSERT INTO dec_tmp(DECSCNR,DECSCPSNR)
     SELECT TRIM (SUBSTRB (qinputstring, INSTR (qinputstring, '|', 1, 2) + 1,11)) dec_nr,
        decoders.decscpsnr FROM bgqueue, decoders WHERE qworktype = 10
        AND decoders.decscpsnr > 0 AND decoders.decscnr =
        TRIM (SUBSTRB (qinputstring,INSTR (qinputstring, '|', 1, 2) + 1,11))
        AND LENGTH (TRIM (SUBSTRB (qinputstring,INSTR (qinputstring, '|', 1, 2) + 1,11))) = 11;

commit;


declare 
 CURSOR smcard_cursor  IS 
     (select d.DECSCNR,d.DECSCPSNR from dec_tmp d);                  


 CURSOR prod_cursor  (v_pslink number )  IS
     (select  p.psdecscpsnrlink, c.CPCSIENTITLEMENTS
        from csiprod c, prodsubs  p
         where p.psdecscpsnrlink = v_pslink
            and c.CPIBSPRODUCTNR = p.psproductnr
            and c.CPCONDITIONNR =1
            and c.cpcsientitlements<>'NILDRA'
            and p.psstatus = 'A' ) ;

   m_decno  varchar2(17) ;
   v_decno  varchar2(17) ;
   prod_line VARCHAR2(1000) ;
   prod_full VARCHAR2(1000) ;
   comma_line VARCHAR2(1000) ;

   prod_len  number ;
   prod_diff number ;
   new_prodct varchar2(300) ;

   L_Size NUMBER ;
   new_size number ;
   s_link number ;
   space_con number ;
   sw number ; 
BEGIN


FOR smcard_record IN smcard_cursor LOOP
   prod_line  := '' ;
   prod_full  := ''  ;
   comma_line := ''  ;
   prod_len   :=0 ;
   prod_diff  :=0  ;
   L_Size :=0 ;
   new_size := 0 ;

   space_con := 0;  
   new_prodct := '' ;


   sw := 0 ; 
   S_link := smcard_record.decscpsnr ;
   v_decno:= substr(smcard_record.decscnr,1,10) ;
   m_decno:= substr(smcard_record.decscnr,1,11) ;


 FOR prod_record IN prod_cursor (s_link) LOOP
    SW := 1 ;
    prod_len := length(prod_record.CPCSIENTITLEMENTS) ;
    prod_diff := mod(prod_len,6) ;

  if prod_diff = 0   THEN 
       new_prodct := prod_record.CPCSIENTITLEMENTS ; 
     else 
      space_con :=prod_len+6-prod_diff ;
      new_prodct := rpad(prod_record.CPCSIENTITLEMENTS, space_con,' ') ;
  end if ;       

  prod_line := prod_line || new_prodct ;
  end loop ;



if sw = 1 then 
 L_size := length(prod_line) ;
 comma_line := comma_line || substr(prod_line,1,6);

for I in 1..L_size  LOOP 
    IF MOD(I,6) = 0 THEN                             
       comma_line := comma_line ||',' || substr(prod_line,(I+1),6) ; 
    END IF;
end loop ;  

 new_size := length(comma_line) - 1 ;
 comma_line := substr(comma_line,1,new_size) ;



prod_FULL :='SOFULL'||','||'002000,'|| v_decno||',EGY,'||'EG,'||'NONE      ,'||comma_line ;

 insert into sf_tmp  (smcard,p_line) values (m_decno,prod_full) ;
 commit ;

end if ; 

end loop ;  
 END;
END;
```

Comment: This is far too broad. Break down your code in to smaller parts, isolate that one feature that is causing you problems. Next you'll be supplying a link to guthub asking us to debug an entire project. Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you don't need '/' at line 10.

Comment: if i remove it i get the same error with "Create"  begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
          null pragma raise return select update while with
          <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
          <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
          insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
          merge pipe purge

Comment: 'END CommandScript;' at the end doesn't make sense to me, as the procedure is ended at line 9;

Can you just run this part of script and let me know the result?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CommandScript IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE sf_tmp';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -942
    THEN
      RAISE;
    END IF;
  END;

Comment: it's working fine but currently i getting an error with Create 
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:    
          ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
          null pragma raise return select update while with
          <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
          <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
          insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
          merge pipe purge

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute DDL in a procedure natively. Wrap it in an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

```
create table sf_tmp(smcard varchar2(17),p_line varchar2(1000));
```

You don't end your `begin` statement, which mean your procedure sees

```
create procedure begin ... declare ... begin ... end ... end
```

You don't need a `declare` in compiled code so this should be:

```
create procedure ... begin ... end ... begin ... end
```

The second `begin ... end` being what you want to execute on compilation (i.e. the creating and dropping of your tables)

You can't reference non-existent tables in a procedure. Given that you're allowing for your table to not exist at the beginning you need to wrap this in an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
insert into sf_tmp  (smcard,p_line) values (m_decno,prod_full) ;
```

Please start using the [ANSI join syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52352), rather than joining in your `WHERE` clause

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax:

[`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030) should help you significantly.

[A global temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) should remove the need to perform DDL in your procedure at all.

Without investigating too hard, your entire procedure looks like it can be done in a single `INSERT` statement...

Lastly, it looks like you're generating partial SQL to be executed later. This *can* be a valid approach in very specific circumstances, but I'd seriously reconsider whether it is before continuing.